# What is the matching VOI LUT function value for EFV_Default in DCMTK library?

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I'm using Dcmtk library and I used the `getVoiLutFunction()` and this function return three different `enum` outputs (`EFV_Linear`, `EFV_Sigmoid`, `EFV_Default`), and for my current CT image I get the the `EFV_Default` value.

I looked into the standard documentation, and I found that a VOI LUT function can have one of three values (`LINEAR`, `LINEAR_EXACT`, `SIGMOID`), and they mention that `LINEAR` in the default one when (*VOI LUT Function*) attribute is absent, I'm confused, what is the matching one for DCMTK's `EFV_Default` `enum`

PS: I'm dealing with CT images.

Comment: Please stick to one question per post. The second question is not only confusing as it's currently written, but also appears to be unrelated to the first one.

Comment: @E_net4, thanks I'll change it according to your recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, EFV_Default is the enumeration literal expressing "not set to a well-known value yet", e.g.:

- in (default) constructor
- when reading a monchrome image for which the VOI LUT attributes are not present

It might e.g. be used to trigger calculation of a window from the image's histogram.

So you should not set this value explicitly but read it as an indication whether the pixel data is non-linear (explicitly set), linear (explicitly set) or linear (by default).

Comment: So, how can I make that transformation having that `EFV_Default` enum return from `getVoiLutFunction()`.

Comment: The same you would do it if you found the value LINEAR.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand that it's up to me to chose the transformation function whether it's linear or segmoid or else if there is an else?

Comment: Yes, up to you or to the user. Depending on the type of image you might find the attribute Pixel Intensity Relationship (0028,1040) telling you whether the raw pixel data is in linear (LIN), logarithmic (LOG) or anything else (OTHER). See https://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/rt-image/rt-image/00281040

Comment: that attribute (Pixel Intensity Relationship) is for RT images and I'm dealing with CT images, I thought that the only attribute that determines the way of transformation is just VOI LUT function!

Comment: Yes, might not be applicable. This is what I was trying to indicate with "depending on the type of image". CT comes in 2 flavors: "Traditional" CT and Enhanced CT.

Comment: Right, according to the documentation of EF_VoiLutFunction, EFV_Default means "default function (not explicitly set)".